# add multiple picture to session in laravel and get it on another function in same controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

blade.php code

[image]

here i store the values to variable

[image]

```
Session::put('customer',$customer);
$customer = Session::get('customer');
```

code to store images in database it works when i use request method but when i use session Serialization error occurs

[image]

Comment: Kindly edit your post in order to make it more readable? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may do it like this.

```
   // Retrieve a piece of data from the session...
    $value = session('key');

    // Specifying a default value...
    $value = session('key', 'default');

    // Store a piece of data in the session...
    session(['key' => 'value']);
```

If you want to read more details about session, visit the link below:

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/session